# Catkin library in Rosbuild package

Tags: catkin, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

**UPDATE: I think I might have resolved the issue. I added the "find_package" and "target_link_library" to the rosbuild CMakeLists.txt**

I'm in the process of migrating some of my packages from ROSBUILD to CATKIN. Unfortunately, I cannot migrate all of them at the moment.
I have migrated a package that builds a library  and now I cannot get the rosbuild package that depends on it to compile.

So, my question is: How do I include a library generated in a CATKIN package in a ROSBUILD package?

This is the CMakeList of the CATKIN package building a library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(catkin_library_package)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES myCatkinLibrary
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
  roscpp
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  include
)


add_library(myCatkinLibrary myCatkinLibrary.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myCatkinLibrary
                      ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                      )
                      
install(TARGETS myCatkinLibrary
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION})
                      
                      
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp")
```

And the CMakeList of the Rosbuild package, which includes the library from the catkin package:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

# The name of the project.
PROJECT(rosbuild_package)


rosbuild_find_ros_package(actionlib_msgs)
include(${actionlib_msgs_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake/actionbuild.cmake)

find_package(catkin_library_package)
include_directories(${catkin_library_package_INCLUDE_DIRS})

genaction()

rosbuild_init()

set(LibraryList
    ${LibraryList}
   )

rosbuild_add_boost_directories()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

rosbuild_genmsg()

rosbuild_add_executable(rosbuild_node src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(rosbuild_node ${catkin_library_package_LIBRARIES})
```

The `CatkinLibraryPackage` contains (amongst other) `/include/catkin_library_package/mylibrary.hpp`, which I'm trying to include in a ROSBUILD package.
The rosbuild_package contains `/src/main.cpp` which specifies in the top: `#include "catkin_library_package/myLibrary.hpp"` All names are substitutes.

The catkin package compiles fine, but when trying to compile the ROSBUILD package, it cannot find the mylibrary.hpp file (a header in the catkin package).

UPDATE: I've been trying to find the answer to the question before submitting the question here, but without luck. However, today I somehow came across [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/201977/include-header-file-from-another-package-indigo/). I added the `find_package(CatkinLibraryPackage)` and the `target_link_libraries(rosbuild_node ${CatkinLibraryPackage_LIBRARIES})` to the CMakeList of the ROSBUILD package. This way, I was able to get the rosbuild package to compile.

**Any inputs on whether this is the correct way is appreciated...**

Thanks to all for your input!

Best regards
Casper

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213264/catkin-library-in-rosbuild-package/) by [cschou](https://answers.ros.org/users/7441/cschou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-07-09**:
Everything seems fine in principle as you described it, but without any detailed information on what exactly you error messages, file layout, workspace layout and cmake files are it is impossible to figure out the problem.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-07-09**:
As @dornhege says, this is a normal migration path. That does not make it simple, there are many details to handle: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html .

**Comment by [cschou](https://answers.ros.org/users/7441/cschou/) on 2015-07-10**:
I was hoping for a "quick" point to some obvious error I had made. Since not the case, I have now updated the question with some code. I have though found a solution in the mean while, but would of course will post the updated info as requested.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-07-10**:
You might need to add the include directories too: CatkinLibraryPackage_INCLUDE_DIRS

**Comment by [cschou](https://answers.ros.org/users/7441/cschou/) on 2015-07-10**:
I did that? It's right under the `find_package(...)`, if this is what you refer to...But you are right, that was indeed needed (perhaps the most important part in order to find the headers in the include folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the issue is that it cannot find the `mylibrary.hpp` file then you've probably not installed the header from the catkin package. This is typically how you'd install the headers in catkin:

```
## Install project namespaced headers
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)
```

Note that the above assumes a structure for your headers as `<package directory>/include/<package name>/mylibrary.hpp`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cschou](https://answers.ros.org/users/7441/cschou/) on 2015-07-10**:
I do have the above in my CMakeList of the Catkin package. However, is there anyway I can check if the header gets installed correctly?

**Comment by [cschou](https://answers.ros.org/users/7441/cschou/) on 2015-07-10**:
I actually found a way to resolve the error, thanks to another post with a reply by you. For that, thank you